# Change external share message base on selected app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, share, external

I'm want to implement external sharing in my react-native application. I have a question: is it possible to change the share message base on the app that user has chosen ? For example:

- If user selects "Messages", "Whatsapp" or "Messenger", the share message will be `this is message A`
- If user selects other apps, the share message will be `this is message B`

I tried react-native [Share](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share) component as well as the [react-native-share](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-share) library, but found no luck so far.